# Joining pageable tables without relation using JPA criteria

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two tables with no modeled relations. in my custom repository like below:

Method one

```
public Page<HistoryTable> findInquiryhistory(InquiryRequest req, int pageNumber, int pageSize){
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return historyRepository.findAll(new Specification<HistoryTable>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<HistoryTable> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                     CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            filterByCarId(predicates,criteriaBuilder, root,
                    req.getCarId());
            filterByCarnameId(predicates, criteriaBuilder, root,
                    req.getCarnameId());
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    }, pageable);
}
```

Method two

```
public Page<DataTable> findInquiry(InquiryRequest req, int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return dataRepository.findAll(new Specification<DataTable>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DataTable> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                     CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            filterByCarId(predicates,criteriaBuilder, root,
                    req.getCarId());
            filterByCarnameId(predicates, criteriaBuilder, root,
                    req.getCarnameId());
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

        }
    }, pageable);
}
```

Is there any possible way join above two method into one code using join, both tables contain groupId as a forign key but its not model relation just relation id wise.is there any possible way to connect above two method into one method use groupId as fk cause i need both in one resultset .Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are after exactly. You want one query to return both HistoryTable and DataTable data, or are you looking at having a single, much more generic method to handle either HistoryTable or DataTable data instances? If the later, you'd have to figure out a common denominator mappedSuperClass for them both.

Comment: Hi @Chris yes i need to return both HistoryTable and DataTable data using one method like which i mention above. simply i need to return pageable  object to return after join two table using criteriaBuilder. Thanks

Comment: "like which i mention above" If you want both HistoryTable and DataTable data returned in one query, that isn't clear in your question. Pagination is the easiest part - You need to give us details on the query you are looking for, the data you are returning (is it a HistoryTable instance, a DataTable instance, a Tuple<HistoryTable,DataTable> or object array, or something else). Is it something like @Query("select h, d from HistoryTable h join DataTable d on d.groupId = h.groupId") you are looking for?

Comment: As per the above example @query won’t work for me cause there lots of filtration have on it.i think its preferred  like <HistoryTable,Datatable> kind of answer